# This issue about keras model and how to compile the model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to create a CNN in pycharm. When I run my code, the console outputs
`RuntimeError: You must compile your model before using it.`

I write down compile. 
This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-o
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, MaxPool2D, Flatten, Conv2D, Dropout
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.optimizers import adadelta

generator = image.ImageDataGenerator(
                rescale=1./255,
                featurewise_center=False,
                samplewise_center=False,
                featurewise_std_normalization=False,
                samplewise_std_normalization=False,
                zca_whitening=False,
                rotation_range=10,
                width_shift_range=0.1,
                height_shift_range=0.1,
                horizontal_flip=True,
                vertical_flip=False,
               )

dateset = generator.flow_from_directory(
               shuffle=True,
               batch_size=100,
               target_size=(80, 80),
               directory='/Users/Username/Documents/Project AI/Dateset/blood-cells/dataset2-master/images/TRAIN')


def model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(80, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu',     
              input_shape=(80, 80, 3)))
    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(optimizer=adadelta(lr=0.001),    
    loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

nn = model()
nn.fit_generator(dateset,steps_per_epoch=None, epochs=30, verbose=1)
nn.save('/Users/yangzichen/Documents/Project AI/Model.txt')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please properly format your code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to overwrite Keras `model()` function with your function. Try this instead:

```
def get_model():  
    model = Sequential() 
    ...
    < *rest of your function code here* >
    ...

    return model

nn = get_model()
```

Comment: i am so sorry, i am a greenhand.thank for you answer , i am so sorry for late reply .i try to rewrite my code, but the issue is not solved, this is output information .i am looking forward to hearing reply as soon as possible

Comment: No worries. What is the issue now? If it is a different problem I suggest you post a different questions and mark this as solved (e.g. by accepting my answer). Otherwise you need to provide more information.